# Removing first word in a string

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a simple way to remove the first word and the following space in a string.

```
//Before
str = "Hello world";
```

Something.

```
//After
str = "World";
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try this:

```
string word = "Hello World";
if (word.Length > 0)
{
   int i = word.IndexOf(" ")+1;
   string str=word.Substring(i);
   Response.Write(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is using ranges since C# 8.0

```
string str = "Hello World";

//One line
str = str[(str.Split()[0].Length + 1)..];

//Multiple lines
string firstWord = str.Split()[0];
int charsToSkip = firstWord.Length + 1;
str = str[charsToSkip..];
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove first word, we need to find it, with Regex it would be cleaner to get it. Then remove is performed by substring.

```
var str = "EXEC STORED_PROC1";
var matchResult = Regex.Match(str, @"^([\w\-]+)");
var firstWord = matchResult.Value; // EXEC
var storedProc = str.Substring(firstWord.Length); // STORED_PROC1
```

Comment: code-only answers are generally not well-received. the point of SO is not only to provide a quick fix, but to _provide knowledge_. please consider adding an explanation about how your solution solves the described problem.